# MIME type error

Tags: cakephp, mime-types

With Cakephp 2.6 I have the following warning:

> Can not determine the mimetype.
>
> Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Below is my Model:

```
 'mimeType' => array(
            'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
            'message' => 'Please only upload images (gif, png, jpg).',
            'allowEmpty' => FALSE,
            ),
```

In php.ini (\xampp\php\php.ini) I uncommented

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

But I still have the same error message.

There is no line number in the error message even if my debug is set to 2. the only error message displaying is : 
`Can not determine the mimetype.Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred`. 
for the stack trace, the value of 'Validation::mimeType(array, array)' is

```
array(
'name' => '2009_Infini-jaune-2.jpg',
'type' => 'image/jpeg',
'tmp_name' => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpEC6C.tmp',
'error' => (int) 0,
'size' => (int) 186994)
```

array(
    (int) 0 => 'image/png',
    (int) 1 => 'image/jpeg'
)`

Comment: How is the `mimeType` value populated? I'm assuming that is where your problem is even though you haven't provided any line numbers or a stack trace. If you can provide more details I'm sure that will help.

Comment: @alecho, there is no line number in the error message even if my debug is set to 2. the only error message displaying is :                        'Can not determine the mimetype.Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred'. for the stack trace, the value of 'Validation::mimeType(array, array)' is `array(
 'name' => '2009_Infini-jaune-2.jpg',
 'type' => 'image/jpeg',
 'tmp_name' => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpEC6C.tmp',
 'error' => (int) 0,
 'size' => (int) 186994
)
array(
 (int) 0 => 'image/png',
 (int) 1 => 'image/jpeg'
)'

Comment: Did you restart the web server and or PHP?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesss!!!! it works now. I just restart xampp. Thank you so much alecho. You are my lifesaver

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'll add an answer so you can accept it and this can be marked as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When enabling or disabling extensions, be sure to restart the web server (or PHP if you are running PHP as a FastCGI instance).

Answer (score 0):

Change the text **;extension=php_fileinfo.dll** into **extension=php_fileinfo.dll** on **php.ini**
It works for me. Hope it helps you guys. I'm using xampp.

Don't forget to restart the web server after that.